# Rspec subject! alters "position" of a before block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I just discovered something in Rspec (after the requisite beating of the head against the wall) that I'm hoping someone can shed light on. I think it involves a misunderstanding I have about Rspec's `subject!`.

My understanding is that `subject!` will run the subject block regardless of whether `subject` is used, and that block will get run at the appropriate time.

What seems to happen, is just that– with the strange side effect that it will cause an *inner* `subject` block to get run *prior to* an inner `before` block.

To wit:

```
  describe 'subject block' do
    before { @var = nil }

    describe 'Test 1: With a bang' do
      subject! { @var = false }
      describe 'inner describe' do
        before { @var = true }
        subject { @var }
        it { is_expected.to be true }
      end
    end

    describe 'Test 2: Without a bang' do
      subject { @var = false }
      describe 'inner describe' do
        before { @var = true }
        subject { @var }
        it { is_expected.to be true }
      end
    end
  end
```

The result of this points out the issue. Test 1, that test with a `subject!` in the outer block, fails. While Test 2, using a non-bang `subject`, passes. The reason Test 1 fails is that the inner `before` block, where `@var = true` is placed, is not called before the inner `subject`, and therefore not called before the actual spec.

This seems wrong to me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My understanding is that `subject!` will run the subject block regardless of whether `subject` is used, and that block will get run at the appropriate time.

"At the appropriate time" is quite vague, so it depends on what you mean by that.
Notice what [the docs](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.2/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/MemoizedHelpers/ClassMethods.html#subject%21-instance_method) say:

> Just like `subject`, except the `block` is invoked by an implicit before hook.

So all [the implementation](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/v3.2.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb#L404-L407) `subject!` does is delegate to `subject` and then define a `before` hook that invokes the subject.

When you have `before` hooks at multiple levels of nesting, the outer context `before` hooks run before the inner ones, as you would expect.  And that's exactly what's going on here.

RSpec's DSL is quite useful when used well, but it can also obfuscate the order things happen in, and when the ordering is important, I think you'll be better off collapsing it into a single `it` that does each thing in the appropriate sequence (or perhaps keeping a single `before` hook for the initial, main setup step).

Comment: What I meant by "appropriate time" was "the same time as `subject`." I was assuming that it would run in the same order as using `subject` without a bang, but because of the implementation with the implicit `before` block, I guess that's not possible. Thanks.

Comment: `subject` doesn't have a defined order when it runs.  It just defines a `subject` helper method that is executed whenever something calls it -- either an explicit call by you in a spec, or by `is_expected` (which is defined as `expect(subject)`).  The entire point `let!` and `subject!` is make the generated helper methods called before the example so that any side effects they produce are in effect for the entire example.  I rarely use those constructs, though.